# How to rewrite URL ".com?foo=bar" TO ".com/bar " and still get the value of $foo

Tags: .htaccess

I have this site, Basilica, which is based on a WP template.

http://www.bazylikaswidnicka.com/wirtualnie/?pan=pan_szopka

I added some PHP stuff to it and the site apparently gets hurt by that ( seo wise ), especially by the section of virtual tours.There I used the ol' good fashioned PHP, structural in form, to catch what a viewer wants to see.

I would like to be able to change the following address:

```
http://www.bazylikaswidnicka.com/wirtualnie/?pan=pan_szopka
```

to:

```
http://www.bazylikaswidnicka.com/wirtualnie/pan_szopka
```

yet still be able to catch the value of $pan. How do I do that?

The .htaccess is already in place by default, it changes all the other links, how do I add this trickery to an extra value in the url to make wonders for this small portion of the website, too?

I don't expect you to write a script for me, but if you can give me a little nudge to where I should turn to that would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this.  You would need to provide anything you wish to allow the page to have access to to be in the URL.

If you are talking about simply retrieving the value from the url then you can do something like

```
$URLPartList =    explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$pan = $URLPartList[1];
```